# Redundancy approach for Pub-Sub application with events replication

Tags: design, architecture, microservices, pubsub, rabbitmq

I'm new to the microservices field.
I'm looking for the right approaches regarding how to deal with the challenge of redundancy of a pus-sub application.
Assume my application has has the below constrains:

1. Real time (very critical)
2. Heavy load time
3. Lots of events
4. Events are metrics (like temperature, stock prices, etc.)

In order to avoid down time, I need probably to instantiate another copy of my application.

Now, if the replication step is right - What should be the strategy for the events replication?
Means, if I'm holding 2 instances of the same application, they both publishing the same data.

I can think of 2 approaches:

- Publisher level
- Consumer level

**Publisher level**

Publisher should know that currently he's in `isActive=false` status.
But, I think it's not the right way.
Why?

- Since the publisher may not be aware of its environment. It sounds that it's not a natural part of its responsibility.
- Who can tell what's the instance `isActive` status?

**Consumer Level**

I'll configure something (if possible...) that I'll ignore the same message if it comes again.
But it looks me too problematic. Why?

- That means my queue (Rabbit) gets twice the same messages. If I have very intensive stream of messages that can lead to a performance issue (IMO).

I'm looking for the standard approaches in this challenge.
Reading material is welcomed too.

Comment: Your publisher-level approach looks like an active redundancy or hot-spare approach. You would then need something to monitor the publishers and tell each of them if they should actively publish (isActive=true) or not.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Do you mean application should implement `isAlive` API? Who is responsible for the monitoring? There is a component which this is its responsibility? Thanks!